# How to get an array's first object element into a state and pass it to a component?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-native, object

How it is possible to get the first object from the response data, and store that in a state?

I've tried something like this, where i use the setData and store the data's first object to it:

```
export default function BuildingsDetail({buildingId}) {
  const [data, setData] = useState({});
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  useEffect(()=> {
    if (!localStorage.getItem('token')) {
      navigate('/login');
    } else {
      fetch(Config.domain + 'kingdom/buildings/:'+buildingId, {
        headers: {'Authorization': 'Bearer '+localStorage.getItem('token')}
      })
      .then(res=>res.json())
      .then(data => {
        setData(data[0]);
      })
    }
  }, [buildingId])
  console.log(data);
  return(
    <div className='container'>
      <div className='building-details'>
        <img />
        <p></p>
        <p></p>
        {data.type === 'Academy' ? <BuildingsButton type={data.type} level={data.level}/> : ''}
        <BuildingsButton type={data.type} level={data.level}/>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
```

I'm getting undefined errors for data.type, which i can't understand since it should be an object which has a 'type' key to it.

Also when im logging out data, it says undefined.

The response from postman is the following:

```
[
    {
        "id": 63,
        "kingdom_id": 31,
        "type": "Academy",
        "level": 1,
        "hp": 100,
        "started_at": 1642410594584,
        "finished_at": 1642410654584
    }
]
```

Comment: How does this output look like:  console.log(data); ?

Comment: Simply undefined

Comment: add the output of console.log(data) to your question

Comment: could you replace the `setData(data[0])` by and `console.log(data)` to see what you get as a response? maybe `data` is not an array so `data[0]` returns `undefined`

Comment: It is an array, since it works just fine with useState([]) and setData(data[0])

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that the problem is that you are trying to display `data` before it's loaded by the `fetch` call.

Change your state default value to `null`:

```
const [data, setData] = useState(null);
```

And add a condition to check if the `data` state is present before rendering the page:

```
if (!data) {
    return <>Loading data...</>
}

return (
  <div className='container'>
    <div className='building-details'>
      <img />
      <p></p>
      <p></p>
      {data.type === 'Academy' ? (
        <BuildingsButton type={data.type} level={data.level} />
      ) : (
        ''
      )}
      <BuildingsButton type={data.type} level={data.level} />
    </div>
  </div>
);
```

It should prevent the error.